# Are shortened URI to Stack Exchange questions stable?

Tags: support, permalink

URI to questions on Stack Exchange may be shortened from:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123456789/my-popular-question
```

to:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123456789
```

Suppose you've been keeping notes locally about your findings on Stack Exchange communities in plain-text files, and that a great number of those plain-text files contain shortened URI to questions on Stack Exchange communities.

My question is: is it safe to write down the shortened URI? Or rather, is the shortened URI **stable**?

The URI provided by the `share` button is somewhat different from what I'm calling a shortened URI.

Comment: You can even shorten it to [`/q/id`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283049) and that goes for answers as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In as far as the number in the URI is the database ID of the post, and unless there's a change to the structure of the site, yes, they're stable.